# jQuery live help

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have the following script which works perfectly until I regenerate the links ".resultLink" via jquery ajax:

```
$("a.resultLink").live('click', function()
{
    var that = this;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'most_used.aspx',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { strMostUsedID:$(that).attr("href") },
        error: function() { },
        success: function() { }
    });
});
```

"live" normally fixes this for me but this time it did not.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause I can think of is the selector not matching, double check that the `.resultLink` class is being applied to the new links...if it's not the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler won't match the selector.